# Proof that if $a/b$ is a perfect square then $a\cdot b$ is also a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It's my first question here, my name is Massimiliano. 
How can I prove that if $a/b$ is a perfect square then $ab$ is also a 
perfect square  *without using* the unicity of prime decomposition?

My work: 
If $a/b$ is a perfect square then there exists $c$ such that $c^2 = a/b$ so 
$c^2b^2 = (cb)^2 = ab$, and therefore $ab$ is a perfect square.

But (to the contrary) if $c^2 = ab$ and  I divide by $b^2$ I obtain 
$(c/b)^2 = a/b$. But I don't know if $c/b$ is actually an integer.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to show that if $a/b$ is a square then $ab$ is a square? That's not what you have written. But anyway $ab=(a/b)(b^2)$.

Comment: I have helped format your question. Please check if what I wrote is correct.

Comment: $a/b$ is not an integer, necessarily. But for rationals it makes sense to ask whether it is a perfect square  as well.

Comment: I'm using only N (natural number 0,1,2,...) and my problem is to demonstrate that if ab is a square then a/b is a square too; but i'm able only to demonstrate that if a/b is a square then ab is a square.

Comment: do we've to show bothway?

Comment: for instance if you take $a=4,b=9$ then $ab$ is a perfect square. but $a/b$ is rational, so do you mean that it's a perfect square in rational?

Comment: Ehm ... yes, please :-)

Comment: Ok , so the inverse is FALSE ! Thank you I'm really sorry !!!

Comment: haha okay . no prob :)

Comment: a statement that is true, and perhaps you want to record is the following: if $ a \cdot b $ is a square and $a$ is divisible by $b$, then $a/b$ is also a square. (and you already have a proof for this!)

Answer (score 4):

If $\frac{a}{b}=q^2$, $a=bq^2$, then $a\cdot b = bq^2\cdot b = (bq)^2$.